# Flutter Scrollable Navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-android

Is it possible to make the NavigationBar scrollable?
My goal is to make a NavigationBar, so you can add up to 15 diffrent Items, if you want.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible, and you don't find navigation bars to be scrollable, good UI design features a few elements at the most in the nav bar.

For a scrollable solution, please check out Tabs: https://material.io/components/tabs/flutter